# PayFlow pro Test Credit Transaction (Refunds)

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I am trying to do refund in test mode  (pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com)  (my currency is GBP just for a FYI)

As far as I can see from the docs I am using everything correctly: https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/payflowgateway_guide.pdf
"Submitting Credit Transactions"
Passing through the ORIGID etc and AMT and I get a success response.

When I log into https://manager.paypal.com and check that the correct amount was refunded it always logs 1GBP

Even if I omit the AMT it only logs 1GBP but if I do a second refund and omit the AMT it tries to refund the original amount (which is obv now no longer the amount as 1GBP has already been refunded) and it gives a 117 error code.

I am wondering if this is only for test mode that it logs this 1GBP and not the amount I specified? I even did a manual refund with the ORIGID in manager.paypal.com itself (on test transaction) and it showed me a success screen with the correct amount but in searching the transaction again it shows it as 1GBP.

Nowhere can I find this behaviour in the docs or online. Does anyone have any info on this?

My only other option is to do a live transaction and refund that but surely testing would need to behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - I just tested full and partial refunds with GBP in test mode and they work as expected for me (no 1GBP issue)

Could you create a throwaway test-only account (per [PART I here](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929/)) -- and if you experience the same issue, log your full NVP request string for the sale and refund and update your question?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this same issue and, at present, it seems to be a minor oversite/bug which is not specified in the documentation. The issue initially was the fact that I had not specified a sandbox email address through the PayFlow manager.

You can find the Sandbox email address by logging into the Manager account, clicking Service Settings at the top, and then by clicking the Setup option. You will find the Sandbox email address in the third section down. This can be any address but you may want to set up a developer account through http://developer.paypal.com . Hope this helps someone